# contradicting examples for series statements

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have tried to find counter examples for the following but without any success. Would appreciate your help:

1. $a_n \to \infty$ then $a_n$ is monotonically increasing
2. $|a_n| \to a$ then $a_n$ converges
3. $a_nb_n \to 0$ then $a_n \to 0$ or $b_n \to 0$
4. $a_n \to K$ (while $K\neq\pm\infty$) then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges

just thought about solution for 2, if I choose unbound series like $(-1)^n$, in absolute value it will be the constant series of (1) thus it converges.
I think that for 3 I have to use also unbounded series, but still no clue.

Comment: will it be a counter example $xsin(1/x)$ for 1?

Comment: Well done. For 3 try and define (bounded) sequences such that $a_n$ becomes very small for even $n$ and $b_n$ becomes very small for odd $n.$

Comment: In 4, start with a geometric sequence and then make it 'stutter', i.e., make every term occur twice.

Comment: Note:  $x\,sin(\frac 1x)$ is not a counterexample for #1.  As $x\to \infty$ those terms converge to $1$.

Comment: I think $xsin(1/x)$ won't work for statement 1 - because when you evaluate the limit of it, it equals 1.

$xsin(1/x) = \frac{sin1/x}{1/x} \to 1$

@lulu yeah just noticed, ideas?

Comment: @Justpassingby I can use something like Dirichlet function for statement 3, right? when n is even then $a_n$ would be 0 when n is odd $b_n$ would be 0.

Comment: For (1) maybe $a_n=n+\cos(n \pi).$

Comment: The $a_n=n+\cos(n \pi)=n+(-1)^n$ is, for $n=1,2,3...$ the sequence $0,3,2,5,4,7,6,9,8,11,...$ which goes to infinity and isn't monotone in any tail end $a_n, n \ge N.$

Comment: For 3 unfamiliar with Dirichlet but you need to make sure that the individual sequences a and b do not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible answers:

1. Consider a sequence like: 1,-1,2,-2,3,-3, $\dots$ that after 1,000 becomes an increasing sequence of 1000,1001, 1002, $\dots$ that would be not monotonically increasing for all $n$. A stuttering sequence here could also work: 1,1,2,2,3,3, $\dots$ as back to back terms could be the same so the $a_{n+1}>a_n$ isn't true for this sequence case.
2. Consider this sequence: 1,-1,1,-1, $\dots$ where for any term the absolute value would be 1 but the sequence merely oscillates.
3. Consider $a_n$=1,0,1,0,$\dots$ and $b_n$=0,1,0,1,0,$\dots$ so that the product is zero for all the terms. yet neither $a_n$ or $b_n$ even converge.
4. i) Consider the sequence of: 0,0,0,0,$\dots$ where the division by zero would be undefined rather than converging even though the sequence does go to zero which is a valid value for $K$.

To use Justpassingby's idea one could have a sequence like:

ii) 1,1,.5,.5,.25,.25,$\dots$ where the ratio test of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ would be 1,.5,1,.5,$\dots$ so the ratio doesn't converge but the initial sequence does converge to zero.

iii) For a non-zero limit of K, just adjust all the terms up a fixed value:

3,3,2.5,2.5,2.25,2.25,$\dots$ so that now the sequence converges to 2 yet the consecutive terms still oscillate back and forth given the back-to-back values. In this case, the value is depending on which subsequence you want to take:

$a_{2n-1}=2+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ which would be 3, 2.5, 2.25, 2.125,  $\dots$

$a_{2n}=2+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ which would be 3, 2.5, 2.25, 2.125, $\dots$

Note that the sequence of $2+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ on its own wouldn't meet the criteria since it does have a monotonically descending property and so the ratio of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ would go to zero if this alone was the sequence. By having a copy of it, the new ratio has this oscillating with 1s for the other ratio as back-to-back terms may be equal half the time as if $n$ is odd and the first term is $a_1$ then $a_n=a_{n+1}$ while if $n$ is even $a_n>a_{n+1}$ since this is where we change the terms.

**Finally a good possibility for $a_n$ without dividing its definition for odds and evens would be $a_n = 3-(1-(\frac{1}{2})^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil})$**

Comment: yeah, 1-3 pretty much what I thought and I do agree. but 4 doesn't seem to be that good

Comment: How about the other case I gave for #4? Don't forget that these aren't exhaustive cases but just one example.

Comment: +1 given second answer to (4)... I wonder if that case can be done for a nonzero limit $K.$

Comment: @JBKing Unfortunately I couldn't understand your solution for statement 4. if you don't mind to mention specific series for an and bn - it might help.
nevermind, just got it - I will think for the specific example

Comment: There is no $b_n$ for statement 4, just $a_n$ and $K$.

Comment: @JBKing ok I just found a good example:
$a_n = 3-(1-(\frac{1}{2})^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil})$